# (Buildroot) "silentoldconfig" error on compile

Tags: ubuntu, compiling, configuration, cross-compilation, buildroot

I just moved an old buildroot folder from an old VM to a newer one to consolidate. I thought that simply moving the folder, along with any dependent folders, and making the appropriate path/name changes would be all that is required to get it up and running in the new VM.

Unfortunately, this appears to not be the case as I am greeted with the following error upon attempting to build in this new VM:

```
#
# configuration written to /home/mirion/mirion/buildroot-2013.05/.config
#
/usr/bin/make -j5  HOSTCC="/usr/bin/gcc" HOSTCXX="/usr/bin/g++" silentoldconfig
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/mirion/mirion/buildroot-2013.05'
BR2_DEFCONFIG='' KCONFIG_AUTOCONFIG=/home/mirion/mirion/buildroot-2013.05/output/build/buildroot-config/auto.conf KCONFIG_AUTOHEADER=/home/mirion/mirion/buildroot-2013.05/output/build/buildroot-config/autoconf.h KCONFIG_TRISTATE=/home/mirion/mirion/buildroot-2013.05/output/build/buildroot-config/tristate.config BUILDROOT_CONFIG=/home/mirion/mirion/buildroot-2013.05/.config /home/mirion/mirion/buildroot-2013.05/output/build/buildroot-config/conf --silentoldconfig Config.in

*** Error during update of the configuration.

Makefile:692: recipe for target 'silentoldconfig' failed
make[1]: *** [silentoldconfig] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/mirion/mirion/buildroot-2013.05'
Makefile:396: recipe for target '/home/mirion/mirion/buildroot-2013.05/output/build/buildroot-config/auto.conf' failed
make: *** [/home/mirion/mirion/buildroot-2013.05/output/build/buildroot-config/auto.conf] Error 2
mv: cannot stat 'output/images/rootfs.ubi': No such file or directory
```

Are there any ideas as to what I can do to resolve this?

I did some poking around on google but could not find anything conclusive.

EDIT: Original VM was running Lubuntu 12.04, the new VM is running Ubuntu 17.10.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I switched to using "olddefconfig" instead, it seems to work.

Comment: A bit more explanation would be appreciated